# How to change submit value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, font-awesome

I have a simple form

*HTML*

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Controler", "FES")" method="POST">
 <button name="upload" type="submit" id="upload-fes-btn-control" class="btn btn-danger">Contrôler</button>
</form>
```

The request time when submitting may sometimes be long (more than 30s, bc of business logic on big file...)

I want to change the value of the button after user has clicked on it. The objective is to display a font-awesome loader instead of the initial text (`<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>`). There is the jQuery snippet I use to achieve this...

*jQuery*

```
$("#upload-fes-btn-control").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('value', '<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
});
```

I'm facing an error due to this code in my Controller

**A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client**

*Controller*

```
if (Request.Form["upload"] != null)
{
   //Logic with ViewModel...
}
```

How can I change the text displayed in the button from text to fa image loader without throwing that error ?

Comment: Just hide it and show the loader

Comment: One way to achieve this would be to have a hidden div with the loader in it. Then on click, hide the button and display the hidden div with the loader.

Comment: Don't set the HTML loader as a value for the button, try `$(this).html('<i class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');` instead

Comment: How about: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/q187vLtu/

Answer (score 1):

use this code `$(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');`

```js
$("#upload-fes-btn-control").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
    //example after page load
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("#upload-fes-btn-control").html('');
        $("#upload-fes-btn-control").html('Contrôler');
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="@Url.Action("Controler", "FES")" method="POST">
 <button name="upload" type="submit" id="upload-fes-btn-control" class="btn btn-danger">Contrôler</button>
</form>
```